# Not getting GitHub merge conflicts Top-bar in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I am having trouble getting this GitHub merge conflict Top-bar to resolve the conflicts in Visual Studio Code.

I have tried adding this command `"editor.codeLens": true` but no effect.

This is what I am getting after pulling the changes [image]

And this is what I want after pulling.
[image]

I am using VS Code 1.70.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that Visual Studio Code has recently introduced the [3 way merge editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_3-way-merge-editor) and has made it the default tool for resolving the merge conflicts.

If you don't feel comfortable using it, you can disable it by going to the following path in the Visual Studio Code settings and removing the checkmark:

path: `settings > extensions > git > Merge Editor`

[image]

Or by directly setting the following in the Visual Studio Code's `settings.json`:

```
"git.mergeEditor": false
```

You **DON'T** need to set `editor.codeLens` to `true` in the settings.