# Why don't merge conflict decorators appear in vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge-conflict, codelens

Strangely, the merge conflict decorators are not appearing in vscode. My "merge conflict > decorators" setting is "enabled", so I am really confused why it is not working. This happened when I installed vscode on my windows computer from scratch. Please let me know what yoy think?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not getting GitHub merge conflicts Top-bar in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368728/not-getting-github-merge-conflicts-top-bar-in-vscode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using VSCode 1.69 (June 2020) or more, there is a [new merge view, which allows a side-by-side resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626228/6309).

But as a result, the old merge conflict decorators are no longer there.

Setting `git.mergeEditor` to `false` might help you to revert to the old behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, setting the git.mergeEditor reverts to the old behavior. That is great to know about the new merge view!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `git.mergeEditor` to false didn't work to me. I had to navigate to extensions and disable `Merge Conflict` extension [image]